# Is there a fundamental difference between 'Default' and 'Legacy ObjectContext' Code Generation

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, objectcontext

I have an Entity Data Model originally built using ef4 which is used for an application of mine.  This application makes extensive use of the C1 studio for Entity Framewaork and as such requires the use of ObjectContext rather than DBContext (at least for the time being).

This model was originally created in visual studio 2010 (where creation of the object context was by default), and then ported over to Visual Studio 2012 and EF5.0 (after having worked out how to create (and maintain an object context model by default).

I have begun to look at porting this application over to visual studio 2013 (but retaining for the time being its use of EF5.0) which bases entity data models on dbContext by default.  There is an EF5.0 Entity Object Generator available on the visual studio Gallery which allows one to create (or presumably update as well) an entity data model using as its Code Generation Strategy 'Legacy ObjectContext'.

So having made a thorough backup of the application I ported it over to vs 2013 with no problems until I went to update the model from the database (having added a few new sprocs I wanted to use). At this point I started to get a whole string of build errors in the model.  I could however open the data model on its own in VS 2012, update it and build it and then reopen the entire application in vs2013 without any issues and again build the entire application without issue.

My question therefore is whether there really is a fundamental difference between the way that the two versions of visual studio build an entity data model based on an objectContext, of if there is one aspect of the Legacy ObjectContext generator that I have missed configuring correctly.

I'd welcome any suggestions or observations.  AS I had said at the start avoiding the ObjectContext is not an option at present.  I expect that to change in the not too distant future but for the time being it can't.  If it means remembering to make adjustments to the model in vs 2012 the so be it.  I'm just curious at present.

Answer (score 4):

The "Default" option was renamed to the "Legacy ObjectContext" in EF6 Tooling shipping with VS2013 (and out of band EF6 tooling for VS2012). The reason for this was that even in VS2012 the "Default" option was no longer default since the "None" option was the default which was pretty amusing.

To clarify in VS2010 and VS2012 the "Default" code generation strategy was using built-in code generators and was generating ObjectContext context and EntityObject based entities. The "None" option would not generate code at all to allow T4 templates added to the project generate the code. In VS2012 the "None" option is default and EF Designer will add T4 templates (.tt files) to your project that will generate DbContext based context and POCO entities.

In EF6 tooling (i.e. VS2013 and the Out of band version for VS2012) the "Default" option was renamed to 
Legacy Object Context" and the "None" option was renamed to "T4". When creating EF6 models the "Legacy Object Context" is disabled because the generated code would be invalid.

If you still need/want to have ObjectContext based context there are T4 templates on Visual Studio Gallery you can download to achieve that. Finally if you have errors after switching code generation strategy to Default/Legacy Object Context make sure to delete T4 templates for the edmx file. Otherwise you will get duplicate set of entities and context (one created from T4 and one from the code generator) which will conflict.
You can find more details on this in a [blog post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/11/10/what-changed-in-the-ef-tooling-in-visual-studio-2013-and-visual-studio-2012-out-of-band/) I wrote a while ago.

Comment: @Pavel Is your Enter key broken?

Comment: @Jowen - not sure what you are asking. If you are alluding to formatting you can edit the response.